# Text Selection with Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, tinymce

I want to select the Text/Word from line or from the Paragraph. How it is possible with Webdriver or with AutoIT?

Example: From the line "One Account. All of Google" , I want to select/click on the Word "Account". also wanted to right click on the work "Account".

Comment: Please give some additional info. Like where does this Example sentence located? On website or in text file(since you are asking for autoIT).

Comment: In my application we are using the TinyMCE, and to test the customized functionality of TinyMCE i need to select some Text/Work from the Textarea/body.

Comment: you might want to look at sikuli. It has OCR support.

Comment: Is there any other option available